# WebRTC with SignalR only working on local network

Tags: asp.net, signalr, webrtc

I'm currently looking for a nice asp.net implementation of webrtc for video chat between two people. 
I found the following example code that I tried and edited but my understanding in webrtc isn't good enough to see why the code only works on local networks and not with people outside of the network.

The project: https://github.com/mgiuliani/webrtc-video-chat

There is also an issue in the github that tells the same problem but I can't find out what the problem is.

Comment: look at https://github.com/alexan1/SignalRTC

Comment: @Alexan thanks for the answer. I'll look at this in the morning. Didn't find that one yet so big help!

Comment: @Alexan it seems to have the same problem. It works when both clients are connected to the same network. But if not, it won't work.

Comment: I left comment on GitHub regarding STUN server. But does my site: https://signalrtc.com/ works? It's exactly the same code. Check your firewall settings.

Comment: @Alexan thanks for your code it really helped alot. But I need to use a TURN server instead of a STUN server and adding the icecandidates needed to wait till the remotedescription was said. (got link for this in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was two things.
First use a TURN server. A Stun server wasn't good enough for my connection. (has something to do with firewalls etc as far as I understand).

Secondly I needed to wait adding the icecandidates till the remotedescription was set, felixhagspiel had a great tutorial on that here:

http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/create-your-own-videochat-application-with-html-and-javascript

Look at the part with 'otherSDP'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably adding TURN server can be beneficial, but in this case problem was with STUN server.

STUN server, which I used: `stun:74.125.142.127:19302`, practically stop working.

I replaced it to: `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` and now my site: https://signalrtc.com/ is working again.

Probably it's better to use several STUN (and maybe also TURN) servers, list of which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/sagivo/3a4b2f2c7ac6e1b5267c2f1f59ac6c6b) and check them [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).

So actually it's enough to use STUN servers, TURN is used as a fallback:

> - A STUN server is used to get an external network address.
> - TURN servers are used to relay traffic if direct (peer to peer) connection fails.

See more information [this tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/).

Comment: run your own stun server. Using more than one stun server slows down candidate discovery, see the Firefox console which warns about this.